# Best subsitute to replace static property

Tags: c#, asp.net, static

I have below static property at my SiteMaster class

```
public static string Success
{
      get { return _Success; }
      set { _Success = value; }
}
```

I can access this property on my child pages

```
SiteMaster.Success = "Saved Successfully";
```

due to this conflicts are occuring

Conflicts means :

```
SiteMaster.Success = "#different messages";
```

set at all child pages of application with different messages .

due to this messages are getting interchanged sometimes and unwanted messages are coming at unexpected events.

please suggest

Comment: what error in terms of "conflicts" is there?

Comment: Please state the problem  clearly, so that you can get some best answers

Comment: "I have a car. It's green. Due to this, problems are occuring. Please suggest."

Comment: For community sake your question should be clear so that you question and all answers could be useful for others not just you so please explain more and the what is the conflict you get

Comment: For SO community: I think OP have a public property in base class, which he can access through sub classed too. This is what he feels as conflict.(This is what I understood)

Comment: If that is your question then this is the answer, *Learn Inheritance.* to avoid this problem make the property private so that you'll not able to access it outside the *base class*

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Making it private *static* won't help one bit if the conflict is due to multiple users accessing the same field "at the same time".

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I hope you're kidding. If that is the case then removing the property will help :P

Comment: No, I'm not kidding. If the conflict is due to multiple users accessing the property at the same time (SiteMaster/child pages -> web application), then the problem is that it is static, not that it is public. So changing public to private will not help one bit. The problem has to either be made non-static, or made into a Thread static, although that's not entirely safe either. Best is to remove the property, but obviously he needs to replace it with something that can work when multiple threads are doing the same thing here.

Comment: Lasse understands my issue , please suggest best way so that I can remove static and it will work with different threads

Comment: I hope you know that a static property is shared among all users! An ASP.Net application is a *single* application that's used by many users (as compared to winforms where each user has his/her own instance). Use `Session` if you want user-specific values.

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this is to create a Session key and store there your message, this will fix the so called conflict for different users.

```
Session["Success"] = "Saved Successfully";
```

Nevertheless your so called conflict will still occur if the same user uses two or more tabs in same browser.

The right way to show messages after a submit is by setting a [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) variable, that's page instance specific.

```
ViewState["Success"] = "Saved Successfully";
```

Comment: using Viewstate will not solve my issue as I need share value between child page and master page